# UISearchDisplayController strange behaviour with searchResultsTableView and self.tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

this is my storyboard view and it's connections:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD0pT.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNnVa.png

In my specific case I have the searchResultsTableView that gets its data from the first external web service and the self.tableview that fetches data from another web service.

I add some code to be clear:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString { ... }
```

this fetched the first web services, in particular 
    return NO

and there is a:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

to reload the data when the fetch is completed.

Then we have:

```
-(void) doSearch:(NSString*) keyword inStore:(NSInteger) store getPage: (int) pagenum {..}
```

that fetches the second web service and set the results in an array called 'fetchedItems'

Now, to manage this two tables I had to write this method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  NSLog(@"Avvio ricerca..");
  // Do the search...
  NSInteger store = [self buttonSelected];
  [self doSearch:searchBar.text inStore:store getPage:1];
  [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
}
```

I tried without the 'setActive:NO' but the self.searchDisplayController.searchTableView remains displayed and I can't se the "underneath" self.tableView with the 'doSearch' results

Ok. Now I have this method:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"foundCell";
      static NSString *suggestionCellIdentifier = @"suggestionCell";
      UITableViewCell *cell;


       if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
         // HERE I AM WITH SEARCHDISPLAYCONTROLLER    

         cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:suggestionCellIdentifier];
         cell.textLabel.text = [self.suggestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      } else {
        // HERE I AM WITH SELF.TABLEVIEW

    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Now it works, but there's a problem!
When i tap on the tableview with the results (denoted by self.tableview) I can't catch the tap with the method** 
    - (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {...}

**but instead I get the re-opening of the uisearchdisplaycontroller in edit mode (so the user can tap inside the searchbar)**

Where am I wrong?

Comment: the problem is given by:

self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;

I think that's an ios 7 bug. This evening i'll check with 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed! When using 
    displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES 
we need that the searchbar is OUT for the tableview in the storyboard!

Comment: What do you mean by OUT ?